# Loading classes dynamically in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

So, I looked into mirror and they might be an option, but given their async nature they might be really awkward to use or just not viable in the long run. Since they are currently not supported (just a play-thing) they are not really viable at this time anyway.

*Question*: Given a series of Strings, eg. `[ "Foo", "Bar" ]` a base class `Application` and `Widget` in `library corelib;` and a corresponding class for each of the strings `FooWidget`, `BarWidget` in `library applibrary;`, what's currently the most elegant method to get `Application` to turn the strings into instances of the corresponding classes, **that works with dart2js**.

Equivalent PHP pseudo-example for clarity,

```php
<?php # example

namespace corelib;

class Widget {
    function name() { 
        return \get_called_class(); 
    }
}

class Application {
    static function resolve($name, $library) { 
        $class = $library.'\\'.$name.'Widget'; 
        return new $class;
    }
}

namespace applibrary;

class FooWidget extends \corelib\Widget {
    // ...
}

class BarWidget extends \corelib\Widget {
    // ...
}

$foowidget = \corelib\Application::resolve('Foo', 'applibrary');
$barwidget = \corelib\Application::resolve('Bar', 'applibrary');

echo "{$foowidget->name()} <br> {$barwidget->name()}";
```

Output

```
applibrary\FooWidget 
applibrary\BarWidget
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can validate the list of strings, then the best way for the moment (until mirror support in dart2js becomes better baked), is likely an `if` statement.

```dart
// toy implementation
Widget getWidget(name) {
  switch (name) {
     case "Foo": return new FooWidget();
     case "Bar": return new FooWidget();
     default: // handle error
  } 
} 

// elsewhere:
var fooWidget = getWidget("Foo");
var barWidget = getWidget("Bar");
```

The list of `xyzWidget` classes will be a finite list (as you can't dynamically link in code at runtime anyway).

Of course, a more elegant implementation is to use mirrors (shown below, for reference, although it doesn't currently fulfil the dar2js criteria)

```dart
Future<Widget> getWidget(library, name) {
  var completer = new Completer<Widget>();
  MirrorSystem ms = currentMirrorSystem();
  ClassMirror cm = ms.libraries[library].classes[name];
  // instantiate an instance of the class
  cm.newInstance(null,[]).then((instance) => completer.complete(instance));

  return completer.future;
}

// elsewhere:   
getWidget("applibrary","FooWidget").then((Widget widget) {
  // do something with widget
});
```

Comment: Was afraid this might be the only way. I'm actually using a similar solution at the moment (as a stop gap measure), only instead of a switch/function I pass a `Map<String, widgetresolver>` to an `Environment` class in the core library and have it execute `widgetresolver` (which is a plain function `typedef`) each time giving me a instance. 

In the mirrors example is there way to make the future synchronous? the whole future there doesn't do a thing for me since I would have to make the application wait on all the widgets to be able to perform cross calculations against one another.

Comment: I like your solution of a widgetresolver.  That's more elegant than a switch statement :).  With regards to having the application wait, surely you need to do that anyway: FooWidget and BarWidget both need to be instantiated before they can do calculations on eachother.

Comment: Well the thing is, since I'm just instantiating a class I don't feel the time wasted in thinking with futures (in the entire application) is of any value. All I want is a bare bone instance of the correct class; if I have to manually initialize it after instantiating it that's fine. A way to have a factory on the `Widget` class that passes me an instance directly, similarly to how I described that I now get an instance out of the `Environment` class would avoid a lot of potential convoluted logic; which is of interest since I want the pseudo `corelib` in the example to be reusable code.